# What is the meaning of "Gateway" in the GCP VPC table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

In GCP in the VPC tool there is a table with these columns:

```
Name
Region
Subnets
MTU 
Mode
IP address ranges
Gateways
Firewall Rules
Global dynamic routing
Flow logs
```

What is the meaning of **Gateway**? Is this the same as **Default Gateway** as described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc)? Why do VPCs need gateways? What do gateways do for the VMs and GKE instances?

Answer (score 2):

An internet gateway is a horizontally scaled, redundant, and highly available VPC component that allows communication between your VPC and the internet.
Also, An internet gateway serves two purposes:
To provide a target in your VPC route tables for internet-routable traffic, and to perform network address translation (NAT) for instances that have been assigned public IPv4 addresses.
An internet gateway supports IPv4 and IPv6 traffic. It does not cause availability risks or bandwidth constraints on your network traffic. There's no additional charge for having an internet gateway in your account.

Comment: In addition, networks usually have a **default route**. The default gateway is the device that handles traffic for the default route. In Google Cloud VPCs, the default route is the first routable address (the second IP address) in a network (x.x.x.1).

Comment: Does the gateway perform NAT for egress traffic from the instance to the outside world or ingress traffic to the instance, or both?